# How to solve a mutant trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, mutating-table

I AM NEW IN PL / SQL ORACLE
I HAVE A PROBLEM, TO MAKE A TRIGGER FOR A MUTATING TABLE

I WANT TO REALIZE THE FOLLOWING: BY INSERTING AN ORDER, ON THE ORDER_ITEMS TABLE, THE ORDERED AMOUNT (QUANTITY) IS RESTED IN THE INVENTORY OF THE TABLE INVENTORIES (QUANTITY_ON_HAND)

```
TABLE ORDER_ITEMS
-ORDER_ID
-PRODUCT_ID-
-UNIT_PRICE
-QUANTITY
```

THE KEY IS ORDER_ID AND IS INCREASED BY A SEQUENCE

```
THE TABLE INVENTORIES
-PRODUCT_ID
-WHAREHOUSE_ID
-QUANTITY_ON_HAND
```

I HAVE PERFORMED FUNCTIONS THAT OBTAIN THE PRODUCT_ID AND THE ORDERED AMOUNT OF THE LAST RECORD INSERTED IN THE TABLE ORDER_ITEMS

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_data__order_quantity
RETURN number IS
quantity_order number;
BEGIN
 select quantity into quantity_order from (select * from ORDER_ITEMS order by order_id desc) where rownum=1;
 RETURN quantity_order ;
END get_data__order_quantity;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_data_cod_prod
RETURN number IS
cod_producto number;
BEGIN
 select product_id into cod_producto from (select * from ORDER_ITEMS order by order_id desc) where rownum=1;
 RETURN cod_producto ;
END get_data_cod_prod;
```

I HAVE PERFORMED THE TRIGGER OF THIS FORM

```
create or replace trigger actualizar_stock
after insert  --AFTER INSERT
on ORDER_ITEMS  -- ON TABLE ORDER_ITEMS
for each row

declare
 ctn_ordenada int;  --STORE THE AMOUNT OF ORDERED PRODUCTS
 cod_produc int;    --STORE THE ID OF THE PRODUCT THAT HAS BEEN ORDERED
 id_wharehouse int; --STORE THE ID OF THE FIRST WAREHOUSE ENCOUNTERED WITH THE PRODUCT IN EXISTENCE
 stock_bodega int;  --STORE THE EXISTENCE OF PRODUCTS (STOCK) IN BODEGA

begin
  ctn_ordenada:=get_data__order_quantity; --THE AMOUNT ORDERED FROM THE FUNCTION IS ASSIGNED
  cod_produc :=get_data_cod_prod;         -- THE PRODUCT ID IS ASSIGNED FROM THE FUNCTION

  select quantity_on_hand into stock_bodega   from inventories where (quantity_on_hand > 0 and rownum=1 and product_id=cod_produc); -- SE ASIGNA EL STOCK
  select  wharehouse_id into  id_wharehouse  from inventories where (quantity_on_hand > 0 and rownum=1 and product_id=cod_produc);  -- THE ID OF THE WAREHOUSE IS ASSIGNED

 -- IF THE ESTOCK IS GREATER THAN 0
 if (stock_bodega >0) then
 begin
 --UPDATE (REST THE CURRENT VALUE WITH THE ORDERED AMOUNT)
 update inventories set quantity_on_hand=quantity_on_hand-ctn_ordenada where wharehouse_id=id_wharehouse;
 end;
 else
  begin
  -- DO NOT UPDATE
  dbms_output.put_line('Registration not updated');
  end;
  end if;
end;

-- END OF THE TRIGGER
```

PLEASE HELP

Comment: Why in all caps?

Comment: Please do not scream in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that the functions `get_data__order_quantity` and `get_data_cod_prod`, which are called from your trigger, access the table that the trigger is defined on. This is going to cause a mutating table exception.

The other problem, of course, is that your functions will very probably not do what you intend. You say "I HAVE PERFORMED FUNCTIONS THAT OBTAIN THE PRODUCT_ID AND THE ORDERED AMOUNT OF THE LAST RECORD INSERTED IN THE TABLE ORDER_ITEMS", but your selection criteria is `...WHERE ROWNUM = 1`. There's no way to know ahead of time what that record will be - in the absence of specific selection or ordering criteria the database is free to return rows in any order it cares to. It *might* return the last row you inserted - but it might return any random row from the table. You simply cannot know, based on ROWNUM=1, that you will get the last row inserted into the table.

Fortunately, you don't need to do any of this, as you already have access to the row which was just inserted through the `:NEW` pseudo-row. I suggest rewriting your trigger as:

```
create or replace trigger actualizar_stock
  after insert on ORDER_ITEMS
  for each row
begin
  --UPDATE (REST THE CURRENT VALUE WITH THE ORDERED AMOUNT)

  update inventories
    set quantity_on_hand = quantity_on_hand - :NEW.QUANTITY
    where QUANTITY_ON_HAND > 0 AND
          product_id = :NEW.PRODUCT_ID;

  IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
    -- No rows updated
    dbms_output.put_line('Registration not updated');
  end if;
end actualizar_stock;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: MANY THANKS FOR THE CLARIFICATIONS, AND THANKS FOR THE SOLUTION THAT IT RAISES. BLESSINGS